# Looping through datagridview and reading the CheckBoxColumn value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with one DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn and some other TextBox Columns. I want to loop through each cell and see if the checkbox is checked then do something. I am using the following looping method. Is there a better way to do??

I have used or condition because in some computers it brings `.Value` as Checked and in some it bring `.Value` as true.

```
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
                {
                    if ((bool)(row.Cells["Checkbox"]).Value || (CheckState)row.Cells["Checkbox"].Value == CheckState.Checked)
                    {   
                        // Do something
                    }

                }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the gridview loaded with boxes checked, or does the user check them and then you want to do something?  If it's the latter, can you not use events to deal with it when the box is checked?

Comment: @Darren: No the boxes are not pre-checked but the user clicks on them. My intention is to collect the data of the checked rows and send them to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me using following code:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_labelprint.Rows)
 {
     if (value.Value == null)
     {

     }
     else 
       if ((Boolean)((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["CheckBox"]).FormattedValue)
       {
          //Come inside if the checkbox is checked
          //Do something if checked
       }

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

i think this will be faster than foreach

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count -1; i++)
 {
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows[i];
    if ((bool)(row.Cells["Checkbox"]).Value 
        || (CheckState)row.Cells["Checkbox"].Value == CheckState.Checked)
    {
         // Do something
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes it is. That's why I was looking for it. 90 % of the solutions here are for each. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link [DirtyCellChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx)  You can then keep track of which rows have been checked and do your work, rather than having to loop through the whole table.

This event is useful when dealing with checkboxes as users sometimes click check, and then don't commit the edit by clicking somewhere else.

It's worked good for me in the past.

Comment: yes but then again I have to remove the rows, if the user unchecks the Box. So, a better option is to let them check all and then loop through the gridview when user clicks the submit or print button

Answer (score 0):

```
int subId;   

List<int> olist= new List<int>();   

for (int i = 0; i < gvStudAttend.Rows.Count; i++) 
{       
   bool Ischecked = Convert.ToBoolean(gvStudAttend.Rows[i].Cells["Attendance"].Value);   
   if (Ischecked == true)    
   {   
      subId = gvStudAttend.Rows[i].Cells["SubjectID"].Value.ToString();   
      olist.Add(subId );   
   }   
}
```